# (Python) Why my inheritence does not work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

```
class Bin():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bin = {}

    def add_to_bin(self, medId , medName):
        self.bin[medId] = medName

    def remove_by_id(self, id):
        self.bin.pop(id)

    def clean_bin(self):
        self.bin.clear()

    def check_ids(self):
        list(self.bin.keys())

    def check_names(self):
        list(self.bin.values())

    def check_inventory(self):
        list(self.bin.items())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bin1 = Bin()
    bin1.add_to_bin(100, "advil")
    bin1.add_to_bin(200, "tylenol")
    bin1.add_to_bin(300, "pepto-bismol")
    bin1.check_inventory()
```

What am I doing wrong? I am so confused.
I am trying to create a medical storage system with multiple dictionaries. Whenever I try to run the code, it does not return anything.

Comment: Your last 3 functions need to return something.

Comment: Which part is wrong?

Comment: ```check_inventory()``` needs to either ```return``` or ```print``` something

Answer (score 1):

Firstly there is no inheritance in your code. It is just a class and object code. Second you need to return data from your methods.

```
class Bin():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bin = {}

    def add_to_bin(self, medId , medName):
        self.bin[medId] = medName

    def remove_by_id(self, id):
        self.bin.pop(id)

    def clean_bin(self):
        self.bin.clear()

    def check_ids(self):
        return list(self.bin.keys())

    def check_names(self):
        return list(self.bin.values())

    def check_inventory(self):
        return list(self.bin.items())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bin1 = Bin()
    bin1.add_to_bin(100, "advil")
    bin1.add_to_bin(200, "tylenol")
    bin1.add_to_bin(300, "pepto-bismol")
    inventory = bin1.check_inventory()
    print(inventory)
    ids = bin1.check_ids()
    print(ids)
    names = bin1.check_names()
    print(names)
```